# Running Sql Scripts On The Start Of The Application

Tags: sql, asp.net

Hi Guys i wanna know how to run few sql script on our application startup 
i am using windows Forms to create a desktop application and have to use this approach for certain task.
database server used is MS SQL

Comment: Hi, can't you create a method and call it on first form page load event? Or you ask about the code of loading a particular sql script?

Answer (score 1):

we have to make a method which call the DB script then script will run and do his work. if your next process is depend on that particular script then you have to first call the script and do your work if your next action is not depend on that script so you can keep those script in thread and you can do your work so it will not take a time to load your start point

Comment: @AndreiMaieras i am aware of calling a method and doing the thing ..
What i was concerned with is there any other way of doing it in asp.net.

Thanks Anurag.. But I thought there is another way of doing it..